# Integers wont append to my array for grid - python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, grid, append

Recently for a school project i've been making a "Treasure hunt" where the player  finds treasure and bandits on a grid in python. I have a way to have the grid at a set size but, as an extra point they ask for us to be able to change the size of the grid, the amount of chests and the amount of bandits.

Here is the code for my grid maker but it wont make the "grid" array but it does for "playergrid":

```
def gridmaker(gridsize, debug):
     global grid
     global playergrid
     gridinator = 1
     grid = [[0]]
     playergrid = [[" "]]
     if debug == 1:
       while gridinator <= gridsize:
         grid[gridinator].append(0)
         gridinator = gridinator + 1
       gridinator = 1
     else:
       while gridinator <= gridsize:
         playergrid[0].append(gridinator)
         gridinator = gridinator + 1
       gridinator = 1
     while gridinator <= gridsize:
       if debug == 1:
         grid.append([0])
         for i in range(gridsize):
           grid[gridinator].append(0)
       else:
         playergrid.append([gridinator])
         for i in range(gridsize):
           playergrid[gridinator].append("#")
       gridinator = gridinator+1
     if debug == 1:
       grid[1][1] = 1
     else:
       playergrid[1][1] = "P"

    gridmaker(9, 1)

    for row in grid:
      print(" ".join(map(str,row)))
```

Sorry if it is formatted differently as there are 2 space tabs rather than 4, it works best on repl.it

print(grid) should return a grid like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Please let me know,
  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that lists are 0-indexed.

Which means that to access the 1st element of the `grid` list you would use the index `0`.

With `grid = [[0]]` you create a list with one item (you can get that item with `grid[0]`), which is a list whose 1st item (`grid[0][0]`) is `0`.

But your `gridinator`'s starting value is `1`. So when your first append runs:

```
grid[gridinator].append(0)
```

it tries to access the 2nd element of `grid`:

```
grid[1].append(0)
```

Which gives you an `IndexError` since, as the traceback should tell you* `list index out of range`.

You can try this yourself:

```
grid = [[0]]
grid[0]
grid[1]
```

One of your solutions could be starting the `gridinator` with 0, and using strict less instead of less or equal here: `gridinator <= gridsize` (because grid[8] gives you the 9th element of the grid).

*Please remember to include the traceback for errors in the future. They really help both yourself and the people trying to help you.

Let me know if this helps, or if I should find another way to explain it.